# Singletons are open in discrete metric

Tags: general-topology

The metric topology with discrete metric is the power set; so all singletons are open in the discrete metric. I am confused why this is.
With the discrete metric, the distance between any distinct points is 1, and we are looking for which subsets are open, i.e. is a union of open balls. But it seems to me that a single point cannot be a union of open balls since it is a since point. Can anyone clarify this, and I am very new to topology so please only use super basic concepts.

Comment: Note that $\{x\}$ is the open ball with center $x$ and radius $1/2$.

Comment: In fact $\{x\}$ is the open ball with centre $x$ and radius $r$ for any $r$ such that $0<r\le 1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you please explain how this is true since it seems impossible for a single point to be any kind of ball?

Comment: If $y \neq x$ then $d(x,y) = 1 > 1/2$ so no other point can be in the ball of radius 1/2.

Comment: You're going to have to abandon most of your intuition about geometry when dealing with topologies like the discrete topology that aren't defined geometrically.

Comment: @Larry: Just apply the definition: the open ball with centre $x$ and radius $1$ is by definition the set $$\{y\in X:d(x,y)<1\}\,.$$ There is exactly one point $y\in X$ such that $d(x,y)<1$, and that is the point $x$ itself: $d(x,x)=0<1$, but for any other point $y$ we have $d(x,y)=1$, and $1\not<1$.

Comment: This is precisely why it is called the *discrete* metric. The only point that is “close” to $x$ is $x$ itself. All other points are “far” from $x$.

Answer (score 1):

In the metric space $S$, the open ball of radius $r$, centred on $x$, is the set

$$B_r(x) := \{y \in S : d(x, y) < r\}$$

If we set $r = \frac{1}{2}$ (or indeed any value less than 1), and $d$ is the discrete metric, then since $d(x, y) = 1$ for $y \neq x$, we must have $B_r(x) = \{x\}$.